# How to configure sasl with Subversion?

Tags: sasl

I have a svnserve runnign and want to set it up with sasl. So I has the following in my svnserve.conf in the repository:

```
[sasl]
use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 256
max-encryption = 256
```

And I have a file in /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf with the following content:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
sasldb_path: /home/subversion/repositories/sasldb
mech_list: DIGEST-MD5
```

I created the sasldb with the following command:

```
sudo saslpasswd2 -c -f /home/subversion/repositories/sasldb -u svnrealm username
```

The sasldb and the svn.conf are readable for the user scvnserve is started with. svnserve was also restarted. But if I try to checkou, I get the following result:

```
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.geoway.de/entwickler'
svn: E170001: Could not obtain the list of SASL mechanisms
```

I use Debian Wheezy. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, a bit more googling provided me the answer. I left all unchanged, only set:

```
min-encryption = 128
```

Then everything works. The error-message was not very telling.

Thanks to this for the solution: https://www.mail-archive.com/users@subversion.apache.org/msg08122.html